# Image duplicate finder

Tags: java, mongodb, hashcode

I have a bunch of exact-duplicate pictures that I've acquired over the years. I'd like to create a list of all them so I can eventually delete some. My idea was simple: dump the hash and location of every image file under a path in MongoDB for later analysis. This is what I came up with:

```
import com.david.mongodocs.ImageEntry;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MD5Deduplicator {
    private static Datastore datastore;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
        morphia.mapPackage("com.david.mongodocs");
        datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "md5Deduplicator");
        datastore.ensureIndexes();
        logDuplicates(Paths.get(args[0]));
        System.out.println("Completed scan in " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime )+ " nanosecs");
    }

    private static void logDuplicates(Path path) throws IOException {
        Files.walk(path).parallel()
                .filter(Files::isReadable)
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .forEach(filePath -> {
                    try {
                        String contentType = Files.probeContentType(filePath);
                        if (contentType != null && contentType.startsWith("image")) {
                            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath.toFile());
                            String md5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(fis);
                            fis.close();
                            ImageEntry imageEntry = new ImageEntry(filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString(), md5);
                            datastore.save(imageEntry);

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

ImageEntry class:

```
package com.david.mongodocs;

import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Indexed;

@Entity
public class ImageEntry {
    @Id
    public final String filePath;
    @Indexed
    public final String md5;

    public ImageEntry(String filePath, String md5) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.md5 = md5;
    }
}
```

From the visualVM profiler it looks like the slowest part of this is the md5hex function (I was a little surprised, I was expecting the slowest part to be related to the `FileInputStream` or save function). Is there perhaps an alternative hashing function or md5 implementation I should use?

I'm also a little worried that `Files.walk().parallel()` might be putting a little bit too much faith in Java defaults and may not be the most optimized way to parallelise this.

Answer (score 2):

The question and the subject is interesting. Recently I needed to make some similar processing; this question pushed me to proceed.

#### Review

First of all, some remarks about the original implementation.

The method `logDuplicates(Path)`, according to what I see, *does not log duplicates*, but saves into mongodb all `ImageEntry` objects corresponding to *all* image files found in the path. So, to trace duplicates, it is still necessary to execute a couple of requests in mongodb.

There is some room for improvements in this method. Calling `datastore.save(imageEntry)` for each item separately looked rather suspicious. Doing it in batch mode for all available items *should* make the thing quicker. Indeed, `Datastore.save` is overloaded with `save(Iterable<T>)` and `save(T... entities)`. A slightly improved version of the method would look like this:

```
private void digestImages(Path path) throws IOException {
  List<ImageEntry> images = new ArrayList<>(APPROX_IMAGES_COUNT);
  Files.walk(path)
       .parallel()
       .filter(Files::isReadable)
       .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
       .forEach(filePath -> {
         if (isImage(filePath)) {
             ImageEntry img = digestAndBuildImageEntry(filePath);
             if (img != null) {
               images.add(img);
             } else {
               System.out.println(String.format("Failed to digest image: %1$s", filePath));
             }
         }});
  datastore.save(images);
}

private boolean isImage(Path path) {
  try {
    String contentType = Files.probeContentType(path);
    return contentType != null && contentType.startsWith("image");
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return false;
  }
}

private ImageEntry digestAndBuildImageEntry(Path filePath) {
  try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(filePath);
       BufferedInputStream buffered = new BufferedInputStream(is)) {
    String hash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(buffered);
    return new ImageEntry(filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString(), hash);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}
```

#### Tests

I've got a folder with about 900 JPG image files in numerous sub-folders that I used for tests. Introducing a `try-with-resources` + batch saving seemed to improve the overall performance for about 10% (see results below).

Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java) that helped me recall different ways and APIs to produce checksums and hashes, I executed a few tests to compare the perfs with the reviewed implementation, as well as when using Guava. The averages of 5 runs on my old i7 gave the following results:

```
impl               avg time,ms    %
-------------------------------------
original              6583      100.0 
reviewed              5873       89.2 
guava/sha1            8267      125.6
guava/md5             5865       89.1 
guava/murmur3-128     3819       58.0
guava/murmur3-32      2689       40.9 
guava/adler32         2432       36.9
-------------------------------------
```

For the tests with Guava, I used the following overloading of `digestAndBuildImageEntry`:

```
private ImageEntry digestAndBuildImageEntry(Path filePath, HashFunction hashFunc) {
  try {
    String hash = com.google.common.io.Files.hash(filePath.toFile(), hashFunc).toString();
    return new ImageEntry(filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString(), hash);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}
```

So, we can see that, at least for my test case and without entering into theoretical discussions, Guava's `adler32` hash performs almost three times faster than the original implementation.

Comment: I considered doing it in batch mode, but I was concerned that putting it into a list would put me at risk of race conditions since I'm parallelising the stream. I would have to use a synchronized list instead and I worried that it would do more damage than individual saves. Also visuamVM seemed to imply that wasnt a pain point really, so I let it be. Your adler32 comment is definitely interesting though, so I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Oups, of course, you are right about the race conditions!.. I've completely skipped this. There shouldn't be this ArrayList, but a concurrent Queue should do the job.

Comment: But would it be faster? (I'd check myself, but I wont be at my home computer for a while).